# Need a float to display in standard form Obj C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, floating-point, decimal

I have an app which is calculating values for a filter. These values are usually within the 10^-9 value. At the moment the value of this calculation is sent to a float. Is there an easy way to force this number to display in standard form? i.e x*10^-9 as opposed to having a long decimal.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a modifier for preparing strings in standard form: `%g` and `%G`:

This doesn't **force** standard form but very large and very small numbers will be in standard form without trailing zeroes. Have a look at the bit I made bold.

> - **%g**
>
> "double" argument is output in scientific or standard format. **Scientific notation is only used if the exponent resulting from the conversion is less than -4 or greater than the precision**; otherwise standard representation is used. With scientific notation, the 'e' to mark the exponent is in lower case. The precision is taken to mean the number of significant digits required (not necessarily the number of decimal places). Trailing zeros are removed from the result, and a decimal point only appears if it is followed by a digit.
>
> - **%G**
>
> same as "%g" format, except that the 'E' to mark the exponent in scientific notation is in upper case.

<sup><sup><sup>[Source](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/printf.html)</sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 3):

You want the [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Specifically, you want to set the `numberStyle` property to `kCFNumberFormatterScientificStyle`. Something like:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numFormatter.numberStyle = kCFNumberFormatterScientificStyle;
NSString *result = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:someFloat]];
```

Comment: this is the nice -- objC way - the pribntf from jimpic would work but isn't .. nice

Comment: you are probably right, but there's no flexibility with this solution, so if you want custom format, my solution would still work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
float yourfloat = [insert here];

float display = yourfloat;

bool neg = false;

if (display < 0)
{
    neg = true;
    display *= -1;
}

int e = 0;

while (display < 1 && display > 0)
{
    display *= 10;
    e++;
}

if (e > 0)
    NSLog(@"%f*10^-%d", display * (neg ? -1 : 1), e);
else
    NSLog(@"%f", display * (neg ? -1 : 1));
```

Of course, replace the `NSLog` by a string or however you need the output.